# Agregar objeto a un ArrayList por medio del Scanner

Tags: java, arraylist, java-util-scanner

Tengo el siguiente codigo en mi main:

```
if (opt1>0){

        switch (opt1){

            case 1: 
                System.out.println("New customer");
                Customer.addCustomer();
                customerList.add(new Customer(getName();getSurname());
            break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Edit customer");
            break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Delete customer");
            break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("List of customers");

                for(int i= 0; i<customerList.size(); i++){
                    System.out.println(customerList.get(i).getName());

                }
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("Invalid Option, Please choose a number between 1 and 3");
                Customer.showMenu();
                break;

        }

        opt1 = 0;

    }else{
        System.out.println("Invalid Option");
        System.out.println("Option has to be a number between 1 and 3");

    }

}
```

y mi metodo addCustomer esta dentro de la clase Customer y es el siguiente

```
public static void addCustomer(){

    System.out.println("Name:");
    setName(name);
    System.out.println("SurName:");
    setSurname(surname);
    System.out.println("E-mail:");
    setEmail(email);
    System.out.println("Phone Number:");
    setPhone(email);


}
```

y el metodo setName y setSurname etc los tengo asi:

```
public void setName() {
    Scanner inputName = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = inputName.nextLine();

}

public void setSurname(String surname) {
    Scanner inputSurname = new Scanner(System.in);
    surname = inputSurname.nextLine();
}
```

Creo q hasta la parte de Customer.addCustomer(); dento del switch funciona bien pero no puedo agregar los datos obtenidos por medio de teclado al arraylist de tipo Customer

```
customerList.add(new Customer(getName();getSurname());
```

podria alguien mostrarme la manera correcta de agregar los datos del objeto a un arraylist llevo ya varios dias intentando y no lo logro.

Comment: [En este enlace viene algo relacionado con tu tema](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/customers/java) Tambien checa tus metodos por que en ningun momento retornas nada ya que tus metodos son void

Answer (score 1):

La manera de leer los datos es la siguiente en la parte de "case 1"

```
case 1: 
    System.out.println("New customer");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Name:");
    String name = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("SurName:");
    String surname = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("E-mail:");
    String email = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Phone Number:");
    String phone = sc.nextLine();

    customerList.add(new Customer(name, surname, email, phone));

break;
```

Y tu clase Customer debe de lucir de la siguiente manera:

```
public class Customer {
private String name;
private String surname;
private String email;
private String phone;
public Customer(String name, String surname, String email, String phone) {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.email = email;
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}}
```